# Animated Eyes - Why are they following when scrolling?

Tags: jquery, cursor, fixed

If you navigate to: http://laboratory.stratusweb.co.uk/lea/ (not yet finished)

You will notice the eyes follow the cursor.

What I can't figure out is why do the eyes move down the page when you scroll?

Any suggestions welcome!

Forgot to add the eyes.js code:

```
var windowX = -1;
var windowY = -1;
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("debugCanvas");
    canvas.width = document.width;
    canvas.height = document.height;
    jQuery(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        var mousePosition = {
            'x' : e.pageX,
            'y' : e.pageY
        };
        var context = document.getElementById("debugCanvas").getContext("2d");
        jQuery(".eyeContainer").each(function(i, i2) {
            var eyeContainerPosition = $(this).offset();
            var eyePosition = {
                'x' : eyeContainerPosition.left + $(this).width() / 2 +1,
                'y' : eyeContainerPosition.top - $('body').scrollTop() + $(this).height() / 2 +1
            }
            var slope = getSlope(eyePosition, mousePosition);
            var toCenterdistance = getDistance(eyePosition, mousePosition);
            var targetDistance = toCenterdistance - ($(this).width() / 2);
            if(toCenterdistance > ($(this).width() / 2)) {
                var x = Math.cos(Math.atan(slope)) * targetDistance;
                if(eyePosition.x > mousePosition.x) {
                    x += mousePosition.x;
                } else if(eyePosition.x < mousePosition.x) {
                    x = -x + mousePosition.x;
                }
                var y = Math.sin(Math.atan(slope)) * targetDistance;
                if(eyePosition.x > mousePosition.x) {
                    y += mousePosition.y;
                } else if(eyePosition.x < mousePosition.x) {
                    y = -y + mousePosition.y;
                }
                x -= $(this).height() / 2;
                y -= $(this).height() / 2;
            } else {
                x = mousePosition.x - ($(this).width() / 2);
                y = mousePosition.y - ($(this).width() / 2);
            }
            var element=$("#eyeBall_" + $(this).attr("rel"));
            element.css({
                'left' : x + 'px',
                'top' : y + 'px',
            });
        });
    })
});
function getSlope(loc1, loc2) {
    return (loc1.y - loc2.y) / (loc1.x - loc2.x);
}
function getDistance(loc1, loc2) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((loc1.x - loc2.x), 2) + Math.pow((loc1.y - loc2.y), 2));
}
```

Comment: omg, looks scary :)

Comment: Maybe you should copy/paste the code moving the eyes, the problem surely is there

Comment: The mouse movements are transformed to the eyes movements by jQuery-based script in [eyes.js](http://laboratory.stratusweb.co.uk/lea/wp-content/themes/shapeshifter/library/scripts/eyes.js).

Comment: Please make this question "self-contained" by posting the relevant code.  Not only is digging through your entire site's code impractical, future readers would not benefit from this after it's fixed.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129787

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
var eyeContainerPosition = $(this).offset();
```

returns a different value depending on how far the page has scrolled -- it returns the offset relative to the top of the document, not the top of the window.

Try replacing the line

```
'y' : eyeContainerPosition.top + $(this).height() / 2 +1
```

with

```
'y' : eyeContainerPosition.top - $('body').scrollTop() + $(this).height() / 2 +1
```

to compensate for that.

Comment: Brill! That's almost got it. Now the eyes don't move, but they don't follow the mouse correctly when you scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

To keep some element on a fixed position on the screen while scrolling, you can specify the CSS style property `position: fixed`.

[W3C documentation on position property.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

**Update:**

When you look at the source code you will see the div `<div class="big_face_holder">` which holds the eyes has indeed `position: fixed` set.

Comment: Why did i get a downvote? The question is why the eyes keep on the visible screen, while scrolling down. I think, i describe the reason.

Comment: The question is, why do the eyes not stay inside the head while scrolling down.

Comment: Ok, but wouldn't it be better to have this fixed via positioning them either `fixed` or event better `relative` to their container and remove the code altering their position?

Comment: If you can't alter their position, then they can't follow the mouse cursor.